# Web Site implicit authentication (SSO) when using localhost

Tags: java, ssh, single-sign-on, authorized-keys

This might be a vague question (sorry), but I'd like to be able to authenticate into my web application without a username/password. Ideally it would be something like the SSH "passwordless login" that uses a private and public key combo.

To clarify this is my Use Case

1. I have a standard Java EE webapp that does a "form" login running on Tomcat. The authentication defers to the OS. So user1 in the webapp is the SAME user as user1 if they ssh-ed into the host.
2. I have a Command Line Interface that works kind of like SSH (ie "cli user@host", then asks for password)
3. I'd like the CLI to just automatically login if I can show the user is trusted.

How do I do this?

One idea I have is to use the ssh-keygen method (ie passwordless ssh). I'm not sure of the exact specifics, but I'd guess it would work something like this.

- In the CLI login I'd use the local private key (ie ~/.ssh/id_dsa) to encrypt some know string.
- post that with the login
- the server goes through each of its "authorized_keys" (probably not the one in ~/.ssh/, but rather one in my application) and try to decrypt the string. If it equals the expected string then SUCCESS

Comments?